# MediaPlayer listing songs in custom listview

Tags: android, listview, media-player, mediastore, android-music-player

So I am trying to build a music player app in android where the list of songs is displayed in a custom listview.
This custom listview contains (custom_list_view.xml):

1. ImageView for album art
2. TextView for song title
3. TextView for song duration

I have created a java class (SongDetails.java) which sets and gets these attributes of a song.

I have created an adapter class (CustomAdapter.java) by extending ArrayAdapter class.

The class MainActivity.java initializes the CustomAdapter and the avtivity_main.xml file has a listview to display the songs

**In the MainActivty.java class, under the addSongs() method, I have requested albumart. I wanted to display album art for every song in the listview. But this line throws an exception. I guess this is because number of album arts and number of songs on the device are unequal causing it to throw an exception. How can I add album art for every song in the listview**

**Here is the MainActivity.java class**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener{

private ListView songsList;
private ArrayList<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>();
private final int MY_PERMISSION_REQUEST_READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE = 1;
private ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdpt;
private ArrayList<String> filepath = new ArrayList<String>();
private ArrayList<String> filename = new ArrayList<String>();
private ArrayList<SongDetails> songDetailsArrayList = new ArrayList<SongDetails>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    songsList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.songs_list_view);

    seekPermissions();
}

public void seekPermissions() {
    if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, MY_PERMISSION_REQUEST_READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
        return;
    }
    addSongs();
}


public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
    switch(requestCode) {
        case MY_PERMISSION_REQUEST_READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE:
        {
            if(grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                addSongs();
            }
            else {
                seekPermissions();
            }
            return;
        }
    }
}


public void addSongs() {
    String[] requestColumns = {MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE,
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.DURATION,
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA,
            MediaStore.Audio.Albums.ALBUM_ART,};
    Cursor cur = managedQuery(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, requestColumns, null, null, null);

    int name = cur.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE);
    int length = cur.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DURATION);
    int path = cur.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA);
    int albart = cur.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Albums.ALBUM_ART);
    SongDetails mySongDetails;
    cur.moveToFirst();

    while(!cur.isAfterLast()) {

        mySongDetails = new SongDetails(cur.getString(name), cur.getInt(albart), cur.getInt(length));
        mySongDetails.setSongDuration(cur.getInt(length));
        myList.add(cur.getString(name)+"\t"+cur.getInt(length));
        filepath.add(cur.getString(path));
        mySongDetails.setSongTitle(cur.getString(name));
        filename.add(cur.getString(name));
        mySongDetails.setAlbumArt(cur.getInt(albart));
        songDetailsArrayList.add(mySongDetails);
        cur.moveToNext();
    }
    songsList.setAdapter(new CustomAdapter(this, songDetailsArrayList));
}
}
```

Comment: have you added permission in manifest file ?

Comment: That was it. Thankyou. Could you also help me how to add album art for every song in the playlist. If you notice I have requested the album art in MainActivity.java class in the addSongs() method. But the app throws an exception. I guess this is because the count of album art and the count of songs on the device are unequal causing it to throw exception. Please tell me how to add album art for every song

Comment: can u put ur custom adapter code ?

Answer (score 0):

The MediaStore.Media.Albums.ALBUM_ART has a return type of String. So replacing integers with strings in all the required places did the trick. And then convert this String to Bitmap image

```
Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(String args);
```

For showing the images on the ImageView use

```
imageView.setBitmapImage(bm);
```